# Robot Framework File Upload getting element not reachable error

Tags: robotframework

I know this has been answered previously. But I could not find any answer how do I get the locator for the pop up window.
I am still getting error while uploading a file from local system to GUI.

1. In my GUI I clicked on Upload arrow button by giving xpath
2. Now File upload window pops up and I need to give a file name in the input field either from my desktop or any local path. - *****I am not sure how do I give locator for the input*****
3. I used Choose File name:File name: C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Generic_1902_User_Input_Spreadsheetenter image description here.xlsx

I am getting element is not reachable by keyboard error. 
Can someone plz upload this video - Check out the video tutorial for Robot Framework File Upload. ([Robot Framework File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113155/robot-framework-file-upload/35217459#35217459))

Even I tried with AutoIT. I could create an au3 file as well as an exe file. However I am not able to call.use this au3/exe file in my robot framework using Python script.

Can someone plz guide.

Answer (score 1):

Do not click on the button that brings up the file chooser window, instead find the `<input>` element by inspecting the page and use its locator directly with the `Choose File` keyword.

For example on Stack Overflow, if you want to edit your question and upload an image, the `<input type="text" class="s-input" id="image-upload-url-input-55038357">` element should be used. Search for similar element on your page under test.

```html
<div class="grid--cell grid fl-grow1 ai-baseline sm:fd-column sm:ai-stretch d-none js-url-input-container">
  <label class="s-label mr8 sm:mr0 sm:mb4" for="image-upload-url-input-55038357">Paste image or link:</label>
  <div class="fl1 ps-relative">
    <input type="text" class="s-input" id="image-upload-url-input-55038357">
  </div>
  <button class="s-btn sm:as-start js-cancel-url">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

To give you an example code, the following snippet will navigate to this question as a quest user and will upload a Capture.PNG (without saving). Note the locator `//*[contains(@id, 'image-upload-file-input')]` for the previous input element.

```python
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${EDIT QUESTION ELEMENT}    improve this question
${UPLOAD IMAGE BUTTON}    //*[contains(@id, 'wmd-image-button')]

*** Test Cases ***
File Upload Test
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038357/robot-framework-file-upload-getting-element-not-reachable-error    Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Click Link       ${EDIT QUESTION ELEMENT}
    Click Element    ${UPLOAD IMAGE BUTTON}
    Choose File     //*[contains(@id, 'image-upload-file-input')]    D:\\Capture.PNG
    Click Button    Add picture
```

Comment: Thanks Bence, This worked for me.

I removed the step for clicking on the button that brings up the file chooser window.
And I directly used Choose File  xpath=.//div/input  C:\\Users\\xxx.xlsx.

This worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: @Sanghamitra Guru Glad to hear, in that case can you mark the answer as accepted by using the tick mark.